# How can i create a Radio group in java code in Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to create Radio group and radio button dynamically in java code for my android application.

Comment: Here you go : http://bit.ly/1bctJ0n

Comment: @ZouZou that gave me a good chuckle lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can add a `TextView` to a `RadioGroup`, but you can try:

```
RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(getContext());

RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton(getContext());
RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton(getContext());
TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());

rg.addView(rb1);
rg.addView(rb2);
rg.addView(tv);
```

Comment: What if I wan't to add one text view and two radio button in a single radio group ?

Comment: Ok, thanx for your valuable comment